# Regex to point to new image location?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an archive of email newsletters. The original source code points to an image at:

http://example.com/email/2015-06-16/weekend.jpg

...but since moving to the archive, now the actual image file exists at:

http://example.com/email/archive/2015/2015-06-16/weekend.jpg

My idea is to use htaccess, regex, and Apache's RewriteEngine to insert "archive/2015/" into the middle of image requests. But I'm not any good with regex. I can describe what I need, but I don't know the syntax to make it happen.

When http://example.com/email/[someyear]-06-16/weekend.jpg is requested, insert "archive/[someyear]/" after "email/"

Please help?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex for this. Try a simple redirect

```
Redirect 301 /email/ http://example.com/email/archive/2015/
```

Comment: Should be `email` to `email/archive/2015`, no?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `mod_rewrite`:

```bash
RewriteRule ^email/((\d{4})-\d{2}.+) /email/archive/$2/$1 [R=302,L]
```

Here, we are capturing the following:

1. `2015` using `(\d{4})` as `$2`, where `{4}` is the amount of digits to capture
2. `06` using `\d{2}` (no need to capture this as we are including it with point 4 below)
3. Everything after `06` with `.+`
4. Everything after `email/` with the parenthises that wrap the above three points

We then put it back together by grabbing `$2` from point 1 above, as well as `$1` from point 4. We only really check point 2 to ensure we're looking at the correct format - this is why we don't check the day (we don't need to be that strict).

Essentially, this is just a shortcut. This could be expanded (for ease of understanding) to the following:

```bash
RewriteRule ^email/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/(.+) /email/archive/$1/$1-$2-$3/$4 [R=302,L]
```

Once you're happy, change `302` to `301` to cache the redirect.